# SQL Queries running with User ID/Login

Tags: sql, sql-server, admin

Is there a way in SQL server to see what queries users are running? I have found info on how to see what queries are running but I am not able to see what user ID or login is running what. I am new to running queries against [sys.] and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT
          r.start_time [Start Time]
        , session_ID [SPID]
        , DB_NAME(database_id) [Database]
        , SUBSTRING(t.text,(r.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 
                     CASE WHEN statement_end_offset=-1 OR statement_end_offset=0 
                     THEN (DATALENGTH(t.Text)-r.statement_start_offset/2)+1 
                     ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2+1 
                     END) [Executing SQL]
        , Status
        , command
        , wait_type
        , wait_time
        , wait_resource
        , last_wait_type
FROM
          sys.dm_exec_requests r
          OUTER APPLY
                    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) t
WHERE
          session_id > 50 --
ORDER BY
          r.start_time
```

but it doesn't show me the login ID. 
At times I want to identify who is running what.

EDIT: Source for above query http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/See%20what%20queries%20are%20currently%20running.aspx

Comment: [SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799(v=sql.105).aspx) will show you what queries are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Profiler (Tools > SQL Server Profiler in SSMS) and create a trace.  There are some other related methods/details described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49448/84000

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiler has NTUserName and LoginName which may help you. Before running a new trace make sure you 'Show all columns' in the 'Events Selection' tab. You can also use 'Column Filters' to filter out your results based on query duration, login names, etc.